# how to stop all NTP synchronizations

Tags: php, ntp

I think I have made ​​several ntp settings, and make synchronization across multiple servers on different timezones.
On my php scripts, date is displayed randmomly for (+2 , +3 timezone ) , for example on first refresh shows 15:08 , for other refresh shows 16:08. 
How to solve this problem ?

Comment: NTP is timezone independent. All NTP communication is in UTC. Your Operating System and/or PHP is converting your time for you, it's not a NTP problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can force PHP to use the value set in php.ini.  Search for date.timezone in php.ini and adjust accordingly.

[date.timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone)